# Sort a list according to the index of the elements in another list

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

I have the following list:

```
A = [0.9,0.8,...,0.1,0.0]
```

and another list:

```
B = [8, 16, 53, 3, 6, 32, 1, 7, 0, 35]
```

How can I make a sorted list similar to another list such that the biggest value in the second list will have the same `index` as the first list?

I want to sort list A like that:

```
A_sorted = [0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.4, 0.0, 0.8]
{B       = [8  , 16 , 53 , 3  , 6  , 32 , 1  , 7  , 0  , 35 ]}
```

How is this possible in Python, preferably in a one line?

Thanks all !

Comment: I don't know how to do it for `list`s, but if these were numpy arrays, I would use `argsort`. Numpy arrays can be rearranged with arrays of indices, and `argsort` can give the indices of `B` that would sort `B`. Except in this case you would rearrange `A` with those indices, like `A[np.argsort(B)]`

Comment: thanks ill look into 'argsort'

Comment: I played with this a little, and `A[np.argsort(B)]` doesn't give the answer. `argsort` rearranges the indices of B to match a sorted B, but you need to rearrange indices of a sorted B to match B.

Comment: the answer I found is A[np.argsort(np.argsort(B))]

Comment: @BatWannaBe lookup my answer. I used your suggestion with a bit of a twist. came out to be very nice. thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer I found was to sort the indexes of B one more time to get the inverse sorting indexes (where was each variable in the original vector)
than use this as an index for the new vector like so:

```
A[np.argsort(np.argsort(B))]
```

I used the suggestion of @batwannabe

Comment: You should mark this as a solution for others to see. It's very surprising to me, but I kind of see why it works: rearranging a `sort(B)` to match `B` has the same moves as rearranging `argsort(B)` to `arange(len(B))`, which is just `sort(argsort(B))`. So to get the indices for that sort, you do `argsort(argsort(B))`.

Interestingly if you just keep `argsort`ing indices, it cycles between two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. create new versions of the two lists, sorted
2. map the sorted values of `B` to the sorted values of `A` using a dictionary
3. build a new version of `A_sorted` by, for each value in `B`, looking up the corresponding value in `B`.

```py
values = [5, 8, 1, 3]
keys = [0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2] 
sorted_values = sorted(values)
sorted_keys = sorted(keys)
merged = dict(zip(sorted_keys, sorted_values))
result = [merged[key] for key in keys]
```

This gives:

```py
>>> keys
[0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2]
>>> result
[1, 8, 5, 3]
```

### Fitting it on one line

If you must, you could mash those statements together into two lines with something like:

```py
merged = dict(zip(sorted(keys), sorted(values)))
result = [merged[key] for key in keys]
```

(or even in one, by inlining `merged`). But you lose readability.

### How to puzzle this out on your own

The key to figuring this out by yourself is realising that you need to create a way to lookup, for any `b`, the corresponding value of `a` in the sorted lists. As soon as you realise this, you realise that you need a dictionary from sorted b to sorted a.

Comment: thanks for the elaborated answer! in MATLAB there is a simpler solution: there is another possible output to sort - the index of the sorting: call it : idx if you sort this idx and take the idx2 of this sort you get the inverse of the sorting. than you use A[idx2] and get A corresponding to B

Comment: I'll try to use your ideas and come up with something like the MATLAB version. without using dictionary

Comment: How would you inline `merged`?

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
a = [2,3,5,6,7]
b = [7,2,3,4,5]
sorted_b = sorted(b)
sorted_a = sorted(a)
for id,i in enumerate(sorted_b):
    idx = b.index(i)
    a[idx] = sorted_a[id]
print(a)
```

Comment: This works, though it runs in O(n^2). By replacing the `index` call with a lookup in a dictionary (e.g. in my answer), you get the runtime down to O(n log n) from the two sorts. Using `id` as a variable name is also frowned upon, since it's a function in `__builtins__`.

Comment: thanks but I rather not use a for loop if I don't have too, avoiding indentation if possible and saving runtime